# Cumulated sum based on condition in other column

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, cumsum

I would like to create a view based on data in following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  date date,
  daily_cumulative_precip float4
);

INSERT INTO my_table (date, daily_cumulative_precip)
VALUES
  ('2016-07-28', 3.048)
, ('2016-08-04', 2.286)
, ('2016-08-11', 5.334)
, ('2016-08-12', 0.254)
, ('2016-08-13', 2.794)
, ('2016-08-14', 2.286)
, ('2016-08-15', 3.302)
, ('2016-08-17', 3.81)
, ('2016-08-19', 15.746)
, ('2016-08-20', 46.739998);
```

I would like to accumulate the precipitation for consecutive days only.

Below is the desired result for a ***different test case*** - except that days without rain should be omitted:

[image]

I have tried window functions with `OVER(PARTITION BY date, rain_on_day)` but they do not yield the desired result.

How could I solve this?

Comment: The result should really match the given test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date
     , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY grp) AS consecutive_group_nr  -- optional
     , daily_cumulative_precip
     , sum(daily_cumulative_precip) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY date) AS cum_precipitation_mm
FROM  (
   SELECT date, t.daily_cumulative_precip
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date) - t.rn AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT generate_series (min(date), max(date), interval '1 day')::date AS date
      FROM   my_table
      ) d
   LEFT   JOIN (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rn FROM my_table) t USING (date)
   ) x
WHERE  daily_cumulative_precip > 0
ORDER  BY date;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=14cf68308f72566a56a29e9026f037bb)*

Returns all rainy days with cumulative sums for consecutive days (and a running group number).

Basics:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

Comment: You did see the fiddle demonstrating that it works? Any crucial information missing? Like your Postgres version?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to calculate cumulative precipitation without having to explicitly enumerate all dates:

```
SELECT date, daily_cumulative_precip, sum(daily_cumulative_precip) over (partition by group_num order by date) as cum_precip
FROM
    (SELECT date, daily_cumulative_precip, sum(start_group) over (order by date) as group_num
    FROM
        (SELECT date, daily_cumulative_precip, CASE WHEN (date != prev_date + 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as start_group
        FROM
            (SELECT date, daily_cumulative_precip, lag(date, 1, '-infinity'::date) over (order by date) as prev_date
            FROM my_table) t1) t2) t3
```

yields

```
|       date | daily_cumulative_precip | cum_precip |
|------------+-------------------------+------------|
| 2016-07-28 |                   3.048 |      3.048 |
| 2016-08-04 |                   2.286 |      2.286 |
| 2016-08-11 |                   5.334 |      5.334 |
| 2016-08-12 |                   0.254 |      5.588 |
| 2016-08-13 |                   2.794 |      8.382 |
| 2016-08-14 |                   2.286 |     10.668 |
| 2016-08-15 |                   3.302 |      13.97 |
| 2016-08-17 |                    3.81 |       3.81 |
| 2016-08-19 |                  15.746 |     15.746 |
| 2016-08-20 |                   46.74 |     62.486 |
```